# iOS load progress bar while requesting  to the web service

Tags: ios, progress-bar

I have a problem loading the progress bar while requesting to web service. I have a TableView and when I click one of the table cells, the page is not responding and after a view seconds the page pushes another view and shows the progress bar.

*How to load the progress bar while requesting to the web service?*

This is my sample code :

```
self.progressHud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.tabBarController.view];
    [self.tabBarController.view addSubview:self.progressHud];   
    self.progressHud.labelText = @"Loading...";
    [self.progressHud show:YES];

  NSMutableArray *myDataRequest = [RequestData getMyDataRequest];

 [self.progressHud hide:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

For the progress bar to update properly you need to perform your long running operations on a background thread and your progress updates on the main thread. That means use an async dispatch queue